# Backend model for group of fields

Tags: magento-2.1, backend, validation, system.xml

Is there a way to have back end model for group of fields in `system.xml`

**I need to validate two fields**. But their validations rules depends on each other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to solve this elegantly, but i was able to solve this good enough.

Using `$this->getData( 'groups/you_group/your_filed' )`, I'm able to access field value from different's one backend model.

So in before_save in backend model of one field, I get value of the other one and can do my validation logic.